# Proof for $\sinh(x-y)$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Basically I need to prove that $\sinh(x-y)=(\sinh x)(\cosh y)-(\cosh x)(\sinh y)$

I could use the fact that $\cosh$ is an even function and $\sinh$ is an odd.

I can prove that:

$$\sinh(x+y) = \sinh x\cosh y+\cosh x\sinh y$$

but I am having a hard time proving it with a subtraction sign in it.

Help please!

Thanks!

Comment: you can always cosider $y$ to be a negative angle say $-y'$. and use what you said you can prove!

Comment: @MichaelHardy Indeed. I will remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace $y$ with $-y$. Then use the fact that $\sinh(-y)=-\sinh(y)$. This can be proven using the definition involving exponents are even using the geometrical definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you *already* know how to prove that
$$
\sinh(x+y) = \sinh x\cosh y+\cosh x\sinh y
$$
and that one is even and the other odd, then all you need is to write
$$
\sinh(x+(-y)) = \sinh x\cosh(-y)+\cosh x\sinh(-y)
$$
and then to apply the fact that one is even and the other odd.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are familiar with complex numbers, you could use the relations to the trigonometric functions $$\sinh(x)=-i \sin(ix) \\\cosh(x)=\cos(ix) $$
which reduces the problem to $$\sin(ix+iy)=\sin(ix) \cos(iy)+\cos(ix) \sin(iy) $$ which is a famous trigonometric identity.

**Remark:**
Using this relationship between the hyperbolic and trigonometric functions in order to transfer identities from one family to to the other is known as Osborne's rule.