# How can this sinh curve be massaged?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, curves, factoring

Sorry I'm new here so I don't know how to use the math symbols yet but I would really appreciate some help with something I'm stuck on.

How can this equation:

$$
()= \sinh(\sinh^{-1}(_0)−\rho \log)
$$

Be reformulated as:

$$
y(x)=\frac{x}{2}\left(\sqrt{1+y_0^2}\left(x^{-\rho}-x^\rho\right)+y_0\left(x^{-\rho}+x^\rho\right)\right)
$$

It is a step that wasn't explained by user26872 in his reponse to the following question: [Name that curve!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156334/name-that-curve)

Thank you!

Comment: They used the formula for sinh(x - y): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598605/proof-for-sinhx-y#598613.

Comment: Yup, that works, I got it thank you!